# When does Solve return root objects and when does it not for cubic equations?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, polynomials

Cubic polynomials always have explicit solutions and Mathematica certainly knows about them.  But Mathematica will by default show the explicit solution only sometimes. I'm guessing there is something about the 'complexity' of the expression that Mathematica uses to choose to hide it as a root object — but does anybody know exactly when it might choose to, or not?

For example, here's a cubic with three real distinct roots that are returned as a root object:

```
Solve[x^3 - x^2 - 3 x + 1 == 0, x]
```

[image]

You can force Mathematica to show the explicit expressions with the following command though the result contains complex numbers. (Even though they should simplify to real numbers, `Simplify` wouldn't do it)

```
Solve[x^3 - x^2 - 3 x + 1 == 0, x] // ToRadicals
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a `Root`, it's usually the better solution. It's just a rigorous representation of an algebraic number. One advantage is that numerical evaluation of a real `Root` yields a real number, while radical expressions are prone to little parasitic imaginary parts.

Comment: @JohnDoty Thanks for the reply though that wasn't what I was asking.  When is a Root shown, and when is the explicit expression shown instead when it exists?

Comment: (1) You can set `Cubics->True`, (2) The remark "...hough the result contains complex numbers. (Even though they should simplify to real numbers, Simplify wouldn't do it)" is simply incorrect, at least if the expectation is that the result will remain in terms of radicals. Look up "casus irreducibilis".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ah!   Thank you   Both of your tips were helpful in understanding more of this question.   Do you think its safe to say that Mathematica will show Root[] whenever the cubic discriminant > 0 ?

Comment: Should have also added, and the rational root test fails?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand what it does with e.g. roots of unity. Probably does not us `Root` in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the real roots of a cubic with three of them in terms of radicals, you wind up needing complex numbers. See [this](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Emurray/Math_421_Eisenberg/Files_to_download__demo__Mathe/CardanBombeliEvaluated.pdf). But you can keep everything real by using `Root`.

If you absolutely must have bronze-age radicals rather than space-age `Roots`, you may give the `Cubics -> True` option to `Solve`.